# Angularjs how to pass in data using a directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

What I am trying to do is make a function so I can change the height of my ng-grid column width.  That is irrelevant besides the fact that the scope from my controller needs to communicate with the scope in my directive.

```
.directive('getWidth', function(){
    return{
        controller: 'QuotesCtrl',
        link: function(scope){
            scope.smRowHeight = function(the value i want){
                scope.theRowHeight = the value i want;
            }
        }
    }
})
```

And I just want to be able to go into my html and say hey for this div I want the height 20

```
<div getWidth = '20'></div>
```

I have looking around and I couldn't find anything doing with this exact thing.  and by the way, in my QuotesCtrl i initialized the row height like so

```
$scope.theRowHeight;
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
.directive('getWidth', function(){
    return{
        controller: 'QuotesCtrl',
        link: function(scope){
            console.log(scope.theRowHeight);
        },
        scope: {
           'theRowHeight': '='
        }
    }
});
```

Markup:

```
<div the-row-height="20"></div>
```

Comment: That didn't work. And it doesn't log anything in the console either.

Answer (score 0):

Directives are amazing! You can pass in what is called an isolate scope, and with that you can pass in values as strings or references to your controller scope. There are 3 options on the isolate scope that you should look into. = @ &  See the link below the example to the docs.

[Here is a working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/311chaos/eaNNf/22/)

```
.directive('getHeight', function(){
    return{
        scope: {
           "rowHeight": '='
        },
        controller: 'QuotesCtrl',
        link: function(scope){
            scope.smRowHeight = function(the value i want){
                scope.theRowHeight = the value i want;
            }
        }
    }
})
```

You would need to update your html to pass in the new scope value.

```
<div get-height row-height='20'></div>
```

[More Info on Directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: This works half-way to what I wanted.  I am trying to have it that i set row-height= '20' and it changes $scope.myheight =20.  I guess that is what I am really asking

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding, but I feel that the fiddle example is doing that. You can change the text box and have it update both the controller value and then the div height. 

Can you explain a little further what I am missing?

Comment: Oh okay.  So when I did this I changed "row-height=myheight" to "row-height=20" so the scope didn't change when i changed row-height.  I want it so that you change it in the div rather than the user picks what the width is.      Edit: So I just looked at your code again and what I want the first div connected to the scope rather than the second one.

Comment: (Another way to say it) I want to set my-height to what ever I want in my div